# openCL ray tracing and branching kernel code issue

Tags: parallel-processing, kernel, opencl, gpu, raytracing

So I'm trying to implement a ray/path tracer using openCL and it seems pretty straightforward - write a kernel that traces the path of a single ray/pixel/etc and have it execute on multiple rays in parallel.

However, when traversing a scene, a single ray has a considerable number of directions it can take. For instance, depending on the material of the hit object, a ray can either reflect or refract. Additionally, different materials require different shading algorithms. For instance, if one scene object requires a cook-torrance shader and another requires a ward anisotropic shader then different shading functions would need to be called within the kernel.

Based on what I've been reading it is unadvisable to have a kernel with branching code inside of it because it hinders performance. But this seems unavoidable in a ray tracer if I am parallelizing my code based on each ray.

So is a "branching" code structure really that much of a hindrance for Kernel performance? If so, how else would I go about structuring my code to account for this?

Comment: instead of branching, save "1" into an array element as "to be branched"("0" for non-to-be-branched) and sort the array such that all brancheds are next to each other, branchless "0"s are next to each other, so SIMD gets what it wants and faster because all elements do same thing(only branch or only non-branch) in multiple passes (iterative) instead of a fake-recursivity(kills performance exponentially). A single radix sort pass could do the thing. What I mean is, in the second pass, kernel looks for "1" to branch and continue tracing the beam and "0" to end and get the color of pixel there.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. First, when you say to use "multiple passes" you mean different kernel calls? And where would the ray sorting take place, in the kernel or on the host? If it's on the host, won't that kill performance? In any event in still not sure of the entire control flow. Like you're saying to have a buffer of rays in kernel 1, trace them till they hit something, then split those up into kernels 2 and 3 depending on where they hit, trace again, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First pass(1M rays),  unsigned char array(or even packed single bits)

```
   ray 0     ------------------  render end  -------------->   0     \
   ray 1     ------------------  surface    --------------->   1      \
   ray 2     ------------------  surface    --------------->   1        }-- bad for SIMD
   ray 3     ------------------  render end  -------------->   0      /
   ray 4     ------------------  surface    --------------->   1     /
   ...
   ...
   ray 1M    ...
```

Sorting(cache or multiplex this for reuse for refraction and reflection)
       with surface type(exists / non existent) and surface position (temporal coherency)

```
   ray 1  \
   ray 2   -------------------- all surfaces --------------> 1   good for simd
   ray 4  /
   ray 0  \
   ray x   -------------------- all render end ------------> 0   good for simd
   ray 3  /

   second pass (refraction)  (1M rays)

   ray 1  ..................... refract ...................> cast a new ray  
   ray 2  ..................... refract ...................> cast a new ray
   ray 4  ..................... refract ...................> cast a new ray
   ray 0  .................... no new ray casting .........> offload some other work/draw 
   ray x  .................... no new ray casting .........> offload some other work/draw
   ray 3  .................... no new ray casting .........> offload some other work/draw

   third pass (reflection) (1M rays)

   ray 1  ..................... reflect...................> cast a new ray  
   ray 2  ..................... reflect...................> cast a new ray
   ray 4  ..................... reflect...................> cast a new ray
   ray 0  .................... no new ray casting .........> offload some other work/draw 
   ray x  .................... no new ray casting .........> offload some other work/draw
   ray 3  .................... no new ray casting .........> offload some other work/draw
```

now there are two groups of 1M rays, doubling at each iteration. So if you have space for 256M elements, you should be able to cast rays until depth7 or 8.  All these could be done on a single array with proper indexing.

Comment: Thanks for this thought out answer. This definitely gives me a starting reference for what I need to do (somehow I'll have to extrapolate from this how to do not just reflection/refraction but also multiple shading algorithms, intersection tests for different shape types etc).

Comment: For the single kernel version, you could start with songle pixel per work group, then branch&generate rays(refr/refl) in that single  work group until there are depth of 6-7(128/256 rays) until work group cant take it anymore, then repeat process with next pixel, such kernel would be slow but I can say kernel launch overhead would be minimal. Using global memory, you could have 30-40 depth easily I think.

Comment: Does an implementation of this method exist somewhere?

Comment: http://cis565-fall-2012.github.io/lectures/09-24-Physically-Based-Shading-and-Pathtracing.pdf a nice work you can look at.